# ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4 - aerial images not in correct postion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, basemap, arcgis-10.4, aerial-photography

When I add aerial images from a recent survey (delivered in EPSG:31468, DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4) to a map document, these differ in position from a basemap as can be seen in the screenshot below (about 150m in ~40°). I carried out these steps:

- Set up a new map document
- Set data frame coordinate system to EPSG:31468
- add the aerial image
- add a basemap (here: openstreetmap)

Overlaying it with a parcel dataset from a different source indicates that my aerial image is positioned correctly, so what have I done wrong?

Aerial vs. osm basemap:

[image]

Overlay with parcel dataset:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have not set a transformation between the datum of your aerial images and the datum of your basemap.  http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000002828

Comment: Convert from `GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz` into `GCS_WGS_1984` (must be added explicitly) and selecting one of the procections (`DHDN_To_WGS_1984_4_NTv2`) solved my issue.

Comment: I think it would be worth you adding that, plus the link I provided as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As determined by PolyGeo this is a transformation issue (http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000002828). Steps to solve this in detail:

Right click Layers, chose properties, 'Coordinate System' tab:

[image]

Click 'Transformations...'

[image]

Note that at this point no transformation method can be selected.

Under 'Convert from:' select `GCS_WGS_1984` and 'Into:' `GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz` (applies for this example):

[image]

Now a transformation method can be selected:

[image]

Click OK. Now the basemap layer matches the aerial image:

[image]