# QGIS 2.14.3. positioning gap between OpenLayers layer and aerial image

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin, aerial-photography, position

When I add aerial images from a recent survey (delivered in EPSG:31468, DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4) to an empty project together with an OpenLayers OSM layer I'm facing a strange positioning issue. I carried out the following steps:

- Set up a new project with 'on the fly' projection enabled and project SRS set to EPSG:31468
- add the aerial image
- add OpenLayers plugin OpenStreetMap layer

The layers positions fit somewhere in the left part of the canvas (screenshots below, green) but dragging the map canvas a few hundred meters causes positioning gaps of the same area (screenshots below, red):

Correct position left of the map canvas:

[image]

Dragging 300m N:

[image]

Dragging 800m E:

[image]

According to the comment to [ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4 - aerial images not in correct postion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200853/arcgis-for-desktop-10-4-aerial-images-not-in-correct-postion) I tried to set up a transformation as shown below, but this seems to have no effect. What might be the reason for this behaviour?

Transformatino settings

[image]

Comment: Does the same issue occur if you instead use the **QuickMapServices** plugin?

Comment: Nope, *QuickMapServices* plugin works pretty well. On the other hand, *OpenLayers Plugin* works pretty well too, when only selecting `EPSG:3857` (WGS 84 - Pseudo Mercator) as the projects srs...

Comment: I noticed there has been a recent update to the **OpenLayers** plugin too but the choice is yours as to which one you want to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Openlayers plugin has always had trouble when the project CRS is not EPSG:3857. QuickmapServices should overcome this.

If you want to stick to OL, set the project CRS as needed, and reproject your DHDN layer to EPSG:3857, on-the-fly or permanently.

Note that EPSG:3857 is not useful if you need to measure lengths or areas.